# Error 400.6 while sending large data with http post request to nodejs https server over IIS proxy

Tags: node.js, https, reverse-proxy, iis-10, arr

My web app takes files from user, slices it to 50mb blobs and sends them with https post request to nodejs https server over IIS proxy server. At the some of requests (like 1 in 30 request), IIS proxy server fails to complete sending whole data and returns 400.6 error.
I maxed out everything related to request connection timeout, filtering size etc. in IIS conf. . But still server fails. What could be the reason for this ?

[image: 400.6 error.]

[image: request]

Note : Windows server 2019, IIS 10, ARR 3.0, nodejs 14.17.6 LTS installed on my server.

Comment: Have you tried sending smaller data to see if it is successful? If successful, then it is likely that your data size exceeds the upper limit of the iis request.

Comment: i installed nginx and its working very well with 50mb blobs, i guess problem is in my iis conf.

`<httpRuntime executionTimeout="2142720000" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />`

`<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" maxUrl="409600" maxQueryString="204800" />`

Comment: In web.config, the factors that affect the size of the request data are maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength. The maximum value of maxRequestLength is 2147483647, and the maximum value of maxAllowedContentLength is 4294967295. you can try to set the maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" and try again.